# Operadores ternarios en swift

Tags: swift, swift2, swift3

¿Es posible hacer `operadores ternarios` en `swift`?

Tengo este tipo de còdigo que repito muchas veces, y queria saber si lo puedo simplificar usando `operadores ternarios`. `condicion ? resultadoTrue : resultadoFalse`

```
if fechaHasta != "" {
    labelFecha.text = fechaHasta
}
```

Comment: Si, aqui tienes la [documentación](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html)

Answer (score 1):

Sin conocer mucho de swift, creo que lo que necesitas es esto:

```
question ? answer1 : answer2
```

Ejemplo:

```
let contentHeight = 40
let hasHeader = true
let rowHeight = contentHeight + (hasHeader ? 50 : 20)
```

En lugar de:

```
let contentHeight = 40
let hasHeader = true
let rowHeight: Int
if hasHeader {
    rowHeight = contentHeight + 50
} else {
    rowHeight = contentHeight + 20
}
```

#### Fuente:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html

Comment: Cierto, me faltó colocar el ejemplo. Ya está editado, revisar a ver si es lo que necesitas.

Answer (score 1):

Sí, de hecho, es igual a muchos lenguajes que también los utilizan (PHP por ejemplo). Para tu ejemplo sería:

```
print(fechaHasta != "" ? labelFecha.text = fechaHasta : "lo que quieras poner si es falso")
```

Te he puesto la función `print` para que lo puedas ver en consola pero lo podrías igualar sin problemas a una variable.

Comment: yo pondría `let labelFecha.text = (fechaHasta != "" ? fechaHasta : "lo que quieras poner si es falso")`

Comment: @lois6b Le pongo un print y así lo puede ver en consola. Luego puede realizar lo que quiera.

Comment: pero el print no tiene sentido si estas asignando el valor de `labelFecha`...

Comment: @lois6b Bueno, lo he especificado con la posibilidad de que lo puede asignar a una variable si quiere.

Comment: @lois6b el ejemplo de Error404 es bastante completo, le esta respondiendo lo que necesita hacer que es un operador, el OP puede ver como ajusta la respuesta a su ejemplo

Comment: @sioesi He intentado ser lo más conciso posible. Si pusiera todas las posibilidades que puede tener con los operadores ternarios en cuanto a funcionalidad se refiere no acabaríamos en mucho tiempo.

Answer (score 0):

Claro es fácil

```
var fecha = ""
fecha = fecha == "" ? labelFecha.text = "no hay fecha" : labelFecha.text = fechaHasta
```

Se compara `fecha` es igual a un string vacío, si es true `labelFecha.text` dice "no hay fecha", `:` significa "de lo contrario" `labelFecha.text` es igual a la variable `fechaHasta`.

Answer (score 0):

```
labelFecha.text = fechaHasta.isEmpty ? fechaHasta ?? "texto"
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo este código responde a la pregunta. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.